# How to create directory like sdcard/MyName in Android 10 and next

Tags: java, android

Problem - I have application, which generates GPX files. They can be stored in application's "files" and shared on user request. BUT some users would like to share (sync) directly - whole directory. Such way they share photos and not only...
My goal - to make directory, and then save files, if user wants so.
Directory like:
sdcard/MyName/
which will contain GPX files for direct share from users.
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" - is not an option. I have time to modify application proper way, ready for Android 11 and next...
Legacy in some moment will be canceled....
When I use code bellow, I am sent to Downloads:

```
public void openDirectory() {
        String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        path+=File.separator+"Downloads"+File.separator+"MyName"+File.separator;
        Log.e("OD",path);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SelDir);
    }
```

I tried also :

```
        File dir=new File(path);
        Uri ui=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",dir);
```

And error:
Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Downloads/MyName
In filepaths.xml - path="."

I tried lot of paths - like MyName, Downloads/MyName ....

Comment: `Legacy in some moment will be canceled..` What do you mean? Even if you target 30 it will work for an Android 10 device. Just use it. For Android 11 all is much simpler again as you have write access to all the public folders on external storage root.